# Why is nuxt generate so slow?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jamstack

I am currently trying to develop a frontend application with [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/). My idea is to generate a static website in which I will inject my database's data (hasura / postgresql).

My application code can be found here: https://github.com/shopozor/services/tree/dev/frontend/consumer-ui

It is pretty minimal. I have a few components: a header, a footer, a map (vue2-leaflet) and I am using the nuxt-apollo module to make client - server communications happen. I have no dynamic routes yet, so right now no remote data gets injected into that static website upon generation.

Sooner or later, I might need to generate the website in production and it will have to be fast. Currently, with the little amount of code I have, it already takes up to 1 minute on a standard computer (intel core i7 3.1Ghz, 32GB RAM, Windows OS).

Can someone tell me what I am screwing up in my nuxt configuration that makes generation so slow?

Comment: Don't worry, it's not your configuration but just Nuxt being slow. You can disable inline CSS and JS minification in the HTML minifier which may improve the build speed.

Comment: For build and generate it's really really slow. But when you run a production mode, this is extremely faster.